# Need to find SQL results based on grouping of single column to find if there is any different value for columns

Tags: sql, oracle

`enter code here`I have one table like below in oracle.

| department_id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 490201 | P4520 | ABC1 | 8000643 |
| 490201 | P4520 | ABC1 | 7000640 |
| 490201 | P4520 | ABC1 | 8000643 |
| 490202 | P4520 | ZYZ2 | 8000643 |

Now if we see above table, for `department_id` 490201 has three entries, we have mismatch value in col3 (700640), there can be many rows with department_id, but their col1, col2, col3 can't have different value. So for each department_id all `col1`, `col2` and `col3` must be consistent.

Now I want to fetch all those department_id using SQL, where any difference found for `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. So final output should look like this because in above sample data only one department_id having mismatch records.

[image]

**Edited**: Not a SQL guy to write complex query, I am writing simple query to pull all records - `select department_id, col1, col2, col3 from meta_test`

And running loop in Python to do work around but data may increased in future so avoiding loop technique with SQL.

Comment: You forgot to include your current query and explain what is not working.

Comment: 1) please don't use images, use editable text so that someone can copy your data and try out a solution 2) please show the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own and then ask a specific question about an issue you are facing

Comment: Updated RAW data into table format and added "Edited" section to highlight what currently being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (department_id, col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 201, 4520, 'abc1', 643 from dual union all
  3     select 201, 4520, 'abc1', 640 from dual union all
  4     select 201, 4520, 'abc1', 643 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 202, 4520, 'zyz2', 643 from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 203, 1234, 'abc1', 200 from dual union all
  9     select 203, 1234, 'abc1', 200 from dual union all
 10     select 203, 1234, 'abc1', 200 from dual
 11    )
```

Query: number of distinct values in `col1`, `col2` and `col3` has to be `1`; otherwise, return that `department_id`:

```
 12  select department_id
 13  from test
 14  group by department_id
 15  having count(distinct col1) <> 1
 16      or count(distinct col2) <> 1
 17      or count(distinct col3) <> 1;

DEPARTMENT_ID
-------------
          201

SQL>
```

Comment: Or... `having not (count(distinct col1) = 1 and count(distinct col2) = 1 and count(distinct col3) = 1)`. I would prefer this because I prefer to use the `=` over the `<>` operator, but of course, this doesn't really matter, just kind of taste.